# How to run nheqminer in background

Tags: server

I am using these commands on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS:

```
sudo apt-get install cmake build-essential libboost-all-dev
git clone -b Linux https://github.com/nicehash/nheqminer
cd nheqminer/cpu_xenoncat/Linux/asm/
sh assemble.sh
cd ../../../Linux_cmake/nheqminer_cpu
cmake .
make -j $(nproc)
./nheqminer_cpu -b
./nheqminer_cpu -l equihash.hk.nicehash.com:3357 -u WalletID.work1 -t 14
```

So if I close the session, mining stops. How can I run this in the background? I tried `screen`, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
nohup ./nheqminer_cpu -l equihash.hk.nicehash.com:3357 -u WalletID.work1 -t 14 &
```